# Is it worth multithreading creating new objects in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create 1 million instances of class HumanInfo, which takes as input an instance of class Human, for which there's lots of extra data I don't need. Class Human won't let me modify the fields, so I created HumanInfo so that I can modify those fields.

```
    public class Human {
        String name;
        double height;
        double weight;
        //thousands of other fields and extraneous information that cannot be modified within Human
    }
    
    public class HumanInfo {
        String name;
        double height;
    }
    
    public HumanInfo(Human human) {
        this.name = human.name;
        this.height = human.height;
    }
```

I tried multithreading this task because there are so many objects to make (and then store in a HashMap). However, it does not go any faster (and sometimes slower) than if I create all instances on a single thread. Is there a reason why multithreading does not help here? Is it because the task of copying information over is too simple to benefit? Is there a different way to speed up this process of creating objects? My real example is different from this, but I believe the idea is the same.

Comment: Possibly because you're not cpu bound. Possibly because you're doing the multi-threading wrong.  I would go with the first assumption since 1 million objects isn't that many, and to create 1 million objects with two fields, it would be pretty hard to improve with threads.

Comment: tl;dr; Add your code, and give us the bench mark times.

Comment: Before considering significant performance improvements in threading, you may want to consider how many cores you have.  Unless you have multiple cores and lots of processing to do using multiple threads won't benefit you.

Comment: Note that if you are wanting the fields not to be modifiable, make them `final`. Also, the JVM is tuned to make creating lots of small objects _extremely_ cheap; in a multithreaded scenario, your overhead is going to be collecting them all in one place.

Comment: I wonder if using a `record` type would help since records are inherently immutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Do not bother trying to optimize a sub-second operation executed occasionally.

## Details

You may have fallen into the trap known as *premature optimization*.

I created two Java 16+ [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) for your `Human` and `HumanInfo` classes.

```java
package work.basil.creation;

public record Human( String name , double height , double weight ) { }
```

```java
package work.basil.creation;

public record HumanInfo( String name , double height ) {
    public HumanInfo ( Human human ) {
        this( human.name() , human.height() );
    }
}
```

Then I wrote this app to populate sample data of a million objects, followed by transcoding those objects from `Human` to `HumanInfo`.

```java
package work.basil.creation;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        int limit = 1_000_000;
        List < Human > humans = app.populateSampleData( limit );
        List < HumanInfo > humanInfos = app.transcodeToHumanInfo( humans );
    }

    private List < HumanInfo > transcodeToHumanInfo ( final List < Human > humans ) {
        Instant start = Instant.now();  // Benchmarking.
        List < HumanInfo > humanInfos = humans.stream().map( human -> new HumanInfo( human ) ).toList();
        System.out.println( "transcodeToHumanInfo  elapsed = " + Duration.between( start , Instant.now() ) );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( humanInfos.get( i ) );
        }
        return humanInfos;
    }

    private List < Human > populateSampleData ( final int limit ) {
        List < Human > humans = new ArrayList <>( limit );
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ ) {
            humans.add( new Human( UUID.randomUUID().toString() , ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble( 145d , 185d ) , ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble( 45d , 90d ) ) );
        }

        // Dump to console.
        System.out.println( "populateSampleData elapsed = " + Duration.between( start , Instant.now() ) );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( humans.get( i ) );
        }
        return humans;
    }
}
```

In my experiments, I changed the `.stream` to `.parallelStream`. I ran each several times, always ignoring the first run. Results were quite consistent.

I am running on [early-access Java 17](http://jdk.java.net/17/) optimized for Apple Silicon (not Intel) on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) with 16 gigs of memory with macOS Big Sur 11.5.1, with 8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency) cores.

### 0.01x seconds

Results:

- Transcoding a ***million objects takes a hundredth of a second*** without concurrency. So no practical point in trying to improve on that.
- Changing that code from `.stream` to `.parallelStream` takes three times longer. Running concurrently *costs* you time rather than saving you time.

Some arbitrarily selected run numbers.

| `.stream` | `.parallelStream` |
| --- | --- |
| PT0.013089S PT0.019682S PT0.018813S | PT0.044404S PT0.043849S PT0.042643S |

You asked:

> Is there a reason why multithreading does not help here?

Because multithreading and concurrency are not magic, there is a cost, an [“overhead”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(business)). Setting up the threads, scheduling their execution times, coordinating their work, and collecting the results are all work that takes time to execute.

When choosing to parallelize, you must consider the costs versus the benefits. This calculation should include some concrete evidence such as micro-benchmarking, as programmers are notoriously bad at guesstimating bottlenecks and optimizations.